Replace a substring found using Regex in a column
I have a table in MySQL 8.  In a varchar column, I want to replace long substrings by another substrings.  I can find those rows using this regex:
SELECT notetext FROM mytable WHERE notetext REGEXP '[a-zA-Z0-9_.:\/-]{25,}';

This Regex searches for all rows that have substrings with length>25.  However, I cannot figure out how to replace the matched substrings by a replacement substring.  I want to do something like this:
  update mytable set notetext = replace(notetext,** regex match ***,  'replacement text') WHERE notetext REGEXP '[a-zA-Z0-9_.:\/-]{25,}'; 

Suppose notetext is "this is the tracking number 8868848848838883399999499494949949949949".  When this is printed somewhere,  it overshoots a print area.   Intent is to break this tracking number by adding a space so that the text is wrapped when printed so the overall text remain in the print area of a fixed length and the print system does not wrap if there is no break in a long word.
"this is the tracking number 8868848848838883399 999499494949949949949"

"I want to replace long substrings by another substrings". Can you rephrase your request. Maybe others understand but I don't seem to. What is the target replacement? Can you show 2-3 lines of before-after for notetext? Or are you saying that if a notetext is longer than 45 it should be of a maximum of 45?

Use REGEXP_REPLACE(). REPLACE() replaces fixed strings, not regular expressions.

So, what is your max length ? it's required to break the string... Where are you showing the data, I mean GUI ?  @AllenKing

I think you're trying to find first 25 characters ...
If it's, use the query:
set @st = 'this is the tracking number 8868848848838883399 999499494949949949949';

select REGEXP_REPLACE(@st, '.*', '', 25) as trim_str;

sample code: db<>fiddle

Alternative Solution: https://dbfiddle.uk/pi3BR8xP

I ended up doing the update table-wide this way.   What it is doing is searching for any substring in the column notetext that is 45 characters or bigger and then inserting a space at index 35 in that substring and updating the column. Middleware should have checked this,  it does now.  This is just to update the old data.  I had to run the same statement many times because there were substring longer than 100s of characters and this statement only takes one breakup at index 35 at a time.
UPDATE mytable SET notetext = REPLACE(notetext,regexp_substr(notetext,'[a-zA-Z0-9_.:\/-]{45,}') ,INSERT(regexp_substr(notetext,'[a-zA-Z0-9_.:\/-]{45,}'),35,0, ' ') ) WHERE notetext REGEXP '[a-zA-Z0-9_.:\/-]{45,}';

